# Unity ScrollView with multiple buttons

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, button, scrollview

I'm developing a game and I've reached a stage in which I need to dynamically create a list of buttons.

My approach was to create a scroll view and then add the buttons through scripting.

I've already created the button prefab. This button purpose is to open a specific link outside the application, so I created the button prefab with two text components: *One saying "Show Path" which is what I want the buttons to show, and the other text component is the link I need to open, which isn't visible to the user.*

I'm running into several problems:

1. I need to create the buttons as I am going through a list of user data. I display the data right beside the button, in another scroll view, correctly. However, only one button is created.
2. I'm unable to access the prefab *link text component* to change it to the link I need to open.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend you do is create your own class to handle this, so it's easier to visualise in the inspector.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class RelevantClassName
{
    public string link = "http://defaultbackuplink";
    public string text = "Default content";

    [Space]

    public Transform button;
    public Transform contentHolder;
}
```

And in a seperate class, you use this information to generate your scroll views and buttons:

```
public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RelevantClassName> contentToDisplay;

    [Header("References"]
    public Transform buttonParent;
    public Transform contentParent;

    public GameObject buttonPrefab;
    public GameObject contentPrefab;

    public void DisplayUI()
    {
        foreach(RelevantClassName content in contentToDisplay)
        {
            content.contentHolder = Instantiate(contentPrefab, contentParent);
            content.button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, buttonParent);

            // And here you can run any custom changes, for example finding a text
            // component on the content holder and changing the description:
            content.contentHolder.GetComponent<Text>().text = content.text;
        }
    }
```

Naturally I heavily advise you use a pooling system, and if you're planning to access a component, cache it in that class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i actually just checked and the buttons are being created, just on top of each other... I used the scrollview viewport as the transform parent and removed the text component from the content inside the viewport, is this wrong?

Comment: You probably want content to be the transform parent of your buttons. The viewport just shows what part of the content is currently in the viewport. When adding buttons you'll probably need to expand the size of the content as you add more buttons.

Comment: Following that logic i just changed the transform parent to the scrollview content, however none of the buttons is displayed, even though they are being created!

Comment: I recommend you switch to using Vertical layouts to ensure the buttons and content lines up together.

Comment: I created the button prefab and the scrollview. Then, i set the scroll view -> Viewport -> Content as the parent. Is this wrong? The content has no component as it is now, and all buttons are being created on top of each other. I've tried adding a content size fitter but it simply does not show any button.

I do not know what you mean with Vertical Layouts.

Comment: Vertical Layout Group is a Component. Add it to the Content game object